# A question in Hilbert spaces

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let be $ X=C[-1,1]$ and define $\langle f,g \rangle =
\int^1_{-1}  f(t)g(t) dt$.

If $M=\{f \in\ C=[-1,1]\mid f\text{ is odd function}\}$, what is $ M^\perp$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What does "$f$ is add function" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily show that $$C([-1,1])=O([-1,1])\oplus E([-1,1])$$ where $O([-1,1])$ denotes the continuous odd functions on $[-1,1]$ and $E([-1,1])$ denotes the continuous even functions. (Hint: $f(t)=\frac{f(t)-f(-t)}{2}+\frac{f(t)+f(-t)}{2}$).

Next, you can show that odd and even functions are orthogonal to each other. Conclude that $O([-1,1])^{\perp}=E([-1,1])$.